# Waydroid installation break config

Tags: display, lxc

I have followed the install instructions here : https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops. I use Debian 12 with Gnome 43.6 and X11 on Dell inspiron 15 laptop. After installation I figured out that Waydroid works only with Wayland so I uninstalled it with the Waydroid instructions. But since the installation I have some broken config. I can't anymore change my screen brightness, Gnome lacks a lot of animations, my screen profile as changed in Gnome color settings and I have an error when I want to set the old profile, I have startup error about missing iwl-debug-yoyo.bin and fatal dhcp error.

I think about a lxc misconfiguration but I can't find any config files.

Is there a way to recover or reset to my previous configurations ? Thanks.

Part of the start up error :

```
[    3.778265] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    3.778297] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    3.778327] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
```